# Inferring type from a known key

Tags: typescript

Consider this type:

```js
export type ListenerToAll<Events> =
  <EventName extends keyof Events>(eventName: EventName, payload: Events[EventName]) => void
```

This fails

```js
type CharacterEvents = {
    wait: {turns: number},
   speak: {message: string}
}

const liToAll: ListenerToAll<CharacterEvents> = (eventName, payload) => {
    if (eventName == 'wait') { // Narrowing
        // TS error: Property 'turns' does not exist on type 
        // '{ turns: number; } | { message: string; }'
        console.log(payload.turns)
    }
}
```

Why can't the type be inferred? It's not enough narrowing? This doesn't make any sense to me.

I tried type guards, switch, etc. TypeScript can understand that the event is known as "wait", but it does not infer the payload type.

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAyBLAzjYA7YKAFQgEEAbcgHgFEA3fGLAPjgF4AoOOWhvGAHIBDALapQuPABMscANbBEEAGZx6jFgApgfQaOAAuNbuFiANHDBDE5CEKlH1-LAG0nesQF0AlO1Z0IDCkODiQUOABhAAshKCEAY1wod1k2OABvLm44AHchDBgjdJgAVyg8LCM8EpEAI0IAXzMsuCwUITkisSwsIQBzQ1aYKAw8PoauCY54iAr4cgwSCnIjTBx8QiXKKmjYhKSU1jTtXQsrGzspXzZWTO4MZRPGdjY0gHI8grffO%20yZiog5GAADpbH1NOdbPZgaVylhvFkJg0gA)

Comment: Problem is that the generic can be instantiated to `EventName = 'wait' | 'speak'` so that the signature becomes `eventName: 'wait' | 'speak'` and `payload: { turns: number; } | { message: string; }` - independent from each other

Comment: Yeah, this is essentially a missing feature, requested at [ms/TS#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808); `K extends keyof T` doesn't mean `K` must be exactly one of the keys.  If you want to use control flow narrowing in your implementation, you might consider switching to a discriminated union of parameter lists instead of generics, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NaRxnm).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz It seems to actually work. Brilliant. Could you elaborate on it in an answer?

Comment: @jcalz Oh that's a cool trick! Does that work only with parameter lists or also in `const` destructuring of the tuple?

Comment: @Bergi you can also do `const` destructuring [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/Wz7V1w).

Comment: The "in a hurry" solution - `if (event==="wait") console.log((payload as CharacterEvents["wait"]).turns)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (as of TS 5.1) [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) does not affect [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters. So  inside a function of type `<K extends keyof CharacterEvents>(eventName: K, payload: CharacterEvents[K]) => void`, checking the `eventName` function parameter can narrow its apparent type, but it does not do anything to the type parameter `K`.  And therefore the type of `payload` is also unaffected, and no correlation between `eventName` and `payload` is inferred.  They are treated as if they were independent.

If `eventName === "wait"`, that does not mean that `K` has been re-[constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) from `K extends keyof CharacterEvents` to `K extends "wait"`.  Indeed it would be technically incorrect to do so, since it is always possible that `K` is *wider* than "wait"`:

```
liToAll(Math.random() > 0.01 ? "wait" : "speak", { message: "abc" }); // okay
```

Here `K` has been inferred as the full [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `keyof CharacterEvents`.  And furthermore that there is a 99% chance that `eventName` is `"wait"` while `payload`  is always a `{message: string}`, so there's a 99% chance that `payload.turns` is undefined at runtime.  Oops.  Looks like `eventName` and `payload` really *aren't* guaranteed to be correlated the way you want (although this sort of thing is probably unlikely and other parts of TypeScript make technically-incorrect-but-very-convenient assumptions also).

That means your desired behavior here wouldn't involve a regular generic constraint.  Instead it would need some new sort of constraint, and is thus a missing feature of the language.  The issue [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) requests one such feature, whereby instead of `K extends keyof CharacterEvents` you'd be able to say something like `K oneof keyof CharacterEvents`, meaning that `K` may only be specified by exactly one member of the `keyof CharacterEvents`.  Then maybe checking `eventName === "wait"` would allow `payload` to be narrowed to `{turns: number}`.

But for now, it simply isn't part of the language.

---

That's the answer to the question as asked, but it might be relevant to talk about an alternative approach.  Currently the only way control flow analysis will narrow one variable when you check another is via [destructured discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions).  So if `eventName` and `payload` are considered to be properties of some value of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type, it will start working.

Discriminated unions require literal-typed discriminant properties... and luckily `eventName`'s type is the string literal type `"wait"` or `"speak"`.  And since `eventName` and `payload` are function parameters, you can consider them as the `0` and `1` properties of the function's [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).  That is, we want your call signature to be the following non-generic type:

```
 (...args: 
    [eventName: "wait", payload: { turns: number; }] | 
    [eventName: "speak", payload: { message: string; }]
 ) => void
```

We can rewrite your `ListenerToAll` utility type to generate such a discriminated union rest parameter type, as follows:

```
export type ListenerToAll<E> =
  (...args: { [K in keyof E]:
    [eventName: K, payload: E[K]]
  }[keyof E]) => void;
```

This is a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)).  Let's test it out:

```
const liToAll: ListenerToAll<CharacterEvents> = (event, payload) => {
  if (event === 'wait') {
    console.log(payload.turns) // okay
  }
}
```

That compiles now; hooray!  And the call from before with `Math.random()` is now rejected:

```
liToAll(Math.random() > 0.01 ? "wait" : "speak", { message: "abc" }); // error
```

Also hooray!  So this is about the closest I can imagine getting to the behavior you want.  The union-of-tuples-as-rest-parameter-type thing is a bit weird, but it works.

Finally, in case it matters, if you want to write this without [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `liToAll`, you'll need to write your implementation's function parameters explicitly as a rest parameter, possibly as follows:

```
const liToAll = (...[event, payload]:
  [event: "wait", payload: { turns: number; }] |
  [event: "speak", payload: { message: string; }]
) => {
  if (event === 'wait') {
    console.log(payload.turns)
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-uF7NEYjEXZFLNY7Cp4okUMlUvLG5khSh7oVEMVnuUlQECKaYzI60o9P0gwjCKObTGqhZaisnBrBsWw1O6NRDigABaWhCHyVwyOOyg-o8JSfK82zIgAVIKAh4e8s7mvO0p7p8kLFmmeYnsEdpgcyEGylIeoxCqu77uUnFZnBPG2mEMyIcsOobPKQxPoCL4pMYKA0ciH5GvsYgoJ6JHnIRkjEacdz5L+-6UW8KDguUPynnaAJAiKoJOZJ3CaP5DJpoiwE1DUxowKaFpWjablhA6gkJDWdYNqF6GMJhjCmacvr+oGwbsmGEYoNGcaJim3GZimsn5uqMCasWpblsMVYoISUhYuwBkoOFhzHCR8ZMbO7FuK5fFhFuIrDeUWbcaNZ4CVK3TCQqwxicqk2+TJdC5nN-EIRqRbaihuqrdsHkhaF3nOX5AVwg0nDBb2YVGZFlrUNa8n2uBzqpc26XpLsRm9V6ABM5mXJZXo2Q8f5PA5+EzrOCCFBAMDnU93VAxJny7eN+HI5AMDVmi2ARSgCzUNQaSpVdvnQrCQVIju4WvdFn3xVKP2hX9TYfq6QxAA)